# Validator to Check if username already exists

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

how can i create a validator that checks if the username typed in a textbox already exists on the SQL database with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and in the `ServerValidate` event, query the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for client-side AJAX like call to validate if the entered username already exists, this [link](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/494/checking-the-existence-of-an-aspnet-membership-username-with-aspnet-ajax) can be useful. It uses Page web method which can be called from client-side scripting.